# Fix iPad status bar orientation as portrait

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, orientation

I have an iPad application with a simple tab bar. I need to fix the orientation as portrait. I do that by setting "Portrait (bottom home button)" in the "Supported interface orientation" field in the plist file.

The problem is that the status bar still move when rotating the iPad... how can I fix it ??

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` from all your view controllers.

Comment: Thanks Ole Begemann. Indeed, I still had a shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in a viewController. I removed it and that works ;)